# google drive api TypeError: Cannot read property 'drive' of undefined or TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

```
import { gapi } from 'gapi-script';
    gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    "name": "settings.txt",
}).execute();

gapi.load('client', function () {
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function () {
        gapi.client.drive.files.create({
            "name": "settings.txt",
          }).execute();
    });
});
```

=> first : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'drive' of undefined`

=> second : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined`

I am trying to create a file using Google Drive api.
However, it does not run as a type error appears.
I used both typescript and Javascript, but it failed.
How do I fix it?

Comment: Lines 2-4 should be inside the `gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function ()`, what you already have. So remove lines 2-4.

Comment: I think you misunderstood gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    "name": "settings.txt",
}).execute();  Running with this TypeError: Cannot read property 'drive' of undefined
    gapi.load('client', function () {gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function () {
        gapi.client.drive.files.create({
            "name": "settings.txt",
          }).execute();
    });
}); Running with this TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined